# async/await returns Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to make a function that reads a file and returns a hash and that can be used synchronously.

```
export async function hash_file(key) {
    // open file stream
    const fstream = fs.createReadStream("./test/hmac.js");
    const hash = crypto.createHash("sha512", key);
    hash.setEncoding("hex");

    // once the stream is done, we read the values
    let res = await readStream.on("end", function() {
        hash.end();
        // print result
        const res = hash.read();
        return res;
    });

    // pipe file to hash generator
    readStream.pipe(hash);

    return res;
}
```

It seems I'm placing await keyword incorrectly...

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: well, if only `readStream.on` returned a Promise... and you won't be able to use that code synchronously, ever. `streams` are async.

Comment: Any function that contains a promise ALWAYS returns a Promise. `async/await` is not "magic" that removes that, and it's simply "sugar" for writing a more natural flow than using `then()`. `readStream` is a "stream" and not a Promise. You can `await` this `hash_file` function to resolve when the "stream" `end` event is fired, if that is what you really want. But's there's "no return value" here anyway, so it's not clear what you are expecting.

Comment: You can never make async results usable synchronously.  Never.  An `async` function ALWAYS returns a promise and `await` ONLY waits when the thing you're awaiting is a promise.  `readstream.on()` does not return a promise so your `await` does nothing useful.

Comment: Well, you really trampled me into the ground here, guys..
What I wanted to do is simply get a hash from this function...

Comment: @avalanche1 the problem is you can't directly. Functions, even async functions return synchronously. So if you want to do something asynchronous in the function and return the result, you need to return a promise because the function returns before the async code is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a
>   Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

`readStream.on` doesn't return a promise, so your code won't work as you expect.

Instead of using `await`, wrap `readStream.on` inside a `Promise` and `resolve` when it ends.

```
function hash_file(key) {
    // open file stream
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./foo.js");
    const hash = crypto.createHash("sha512", key);
    hash.setEncoding("hex");

    // once the stream is done, we read the values
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        readStream.on("end", () => {
            hash.end();
            // print result
            resolve(hash.read());
        });

        readStream.on("error", reject);

        // pipe file to hash generator
        readStream.pipe(hash);
    });
}
```

> I'm trying to make a function that reads a file and returns a hash and
>   **that can be used synchronously**

This won't happen, ever. You can't make async code be synchronous. You can make it look like it's synchronous, using `async/await` but it will always be asynchronous.

```
(async() => {
    const hash = await hash_file('my-key'); // This is async.
    console.log(hash);
})();
```